# Expected value of trials for "two in a row"

Tags: statistics, expected-value, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

**Problem.** You are practicing archery.  The probability that you hit a bull's eye is 0.2.  Assume that each attempt is independent of all the others.  Let $T$ denote the number of tries needed to hit two bull's eyes in succession, and $\mathbb{E}[T]$ its expectation.  Also let $W$ denote the RV that takes the value 1 if you hit bull's eye on your first attempt and 0 otherwise.

**i.**  Write down an expression for $\mathbb{E}[T|W=0]$ as a function of $\mathbb{E}[T]$.

**ii.**  Write down an expression for $\mathbb{E}[T|W=1]$ as a function of $\mathbb{E}[T]$.

**iii.**  Compute $\mathbb{E}[T]$.

*Attempted solution for i.*  My intuition tells me that if we miss the first time, things "start over" so that $P(T=t|W=0)=P(T=t-1)$ whenever $t\geq 3$.  Hence:
$$
\mathbb{E}[T|W=0]=\sum_{t=3}^\infty tP(T=t|W=0)
$$
$$
=\sum_{t=3}^\infty tP(T=t-1)
$$
$$
=\sum_{t=3}^\infty (t-1)P(T=t-1)+\sum_{t=3}^\infty P(T=t-1)
$$
$$
=\sum_{t=2}^\infty tP(T=t)+\sum_{t=2}^\infty P(T=t)
$$
$$
=\mathbb{E}(T)+\sum_{t=2}^\infty P(T=t)
$$
$$
=\mathbb{E}(T)+1.
$$
However, I'm uncertain of how to prove $P(T=t|W=0)=P(T=t-1)$ rigorously.

*Attempted solution for ii.*  For $t\geq 4$ we have
$$
P(T=t|W=1)=P(T=t|\text{make first and miss second}).
$$
Again, using intuition, I believe that
$$
P(T=t|\text{make first and miss second})=P(T=t-2)
$$
hence
$$
P(T=t|W=1)=P(T=t-2)
$$
Now, similar to before,
$$
\mathbb{E}(T|W=1)=\sum_{t=2}^\infty tP(T=t|W=1)
$$
$$
=2P(T=2|W=1)+\sum_{t=4}^\infty tP(T=t|W=1)
$$
$$
=2(0.2)+\sum_{t=4}^\infty tP(T=t-2)
$$
$$
=0.4+\sum_{t=2}^\infty tP(T=t)+2
$$
$$
=\mathbb{E}[T]+2.4.
$$

*Attempted solution for iii.*  If my answers to (i) and (ii) are correct, then, setting $\mu=\mathbb{E}[T]$, we obtain
$$
\mu=0.8\mathbb{E}[T|W=0]+0.2\mathbb{E}[T|W=1]
$$
$$
=0.8(\mu+1)+0.2(\mu+2.4)=\mu+1.28
$$
which is clearly nonsense.  So, obviously at least one---probably more---serious errors are involved above.

Any ideas what the trouble is?

Thanks!

Comment: When computing $E(T \mid W=1)$, where does the $2$ in $2 P(T=t \mid W=1)$ comes from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$E[T|W=0]=1+E[T]$$

That is after the first failure, the game restart.

If your first trial is a hit, there are two possibilities, you end the game by hitting it the second time or you don't and restart the game.
\begin{align}
E[T|W=1] &=2p + (1-p)(2+E[T))\\
&=2+(1-p)E[T]
\end{align}

Another interpretation is that we need $T\ge 2$, the probability that we have to restart the game is $1-p$.

Now, using the total law of expectation.

\begin{align}
E[T] &= pE[T|W=1]+(1-p)E[T|W=0]\\
&=p[2+(1-p)E[T]] + (1-p)[1+E[T]]\\
&=2p+1-p+[(1+p)(1-p)E[T]\\
&=p+1+(1-p^2)E[T]\\
&= \frac{p+1}{p^2}
\end{align}